# How to make font FuturaPtBooks available in html

Tags: html, css, fonts

Hi guys I have a question
I want to use FuturaPtBook, but it isn't displayed in html as the real font.
What can I do ?

```
        <a  href="#" style="font-family: 'Futura Book', Arial, sans-serif;font-weight: 400;" class="navbar-brand"><span></span> Hello</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the @font-face rule.

1. Either obtain or create your custom font file.
2. Upload the font file(s) to your server under your Web root.
3. Add this code to either your CSS or `<style>` tags in the HTML header:

   @font-face{
   font-family: Futura Book; 
   src: url('the URL the file should be downloaded from');
   }